# Matching of user search keywords to tags

Tags: database, t-sql, full-text-search, tags

Can somebody advise idea, how to match user input (few words) to appropriate tags in system (each of them also 1 or N words)?

Here is sample to demonstrate problem:
I have a Tags, assigned to objects. For example (tags are separated by COMA, but in real life I have relation to table)

```
Object                  Tags
Earth                   World, reality
World of warcraft 3     World Of warcraft, virtual reality
quake                   game, virtual
```

I would like to get following:

User Enter '**World**': result is '**Earth**'

User Enter '**World of warcraft**': result is '**world of warcraft 3**'

That was simple, exact search. But:

User Enter '**game world**': results should be search by two tags - '**earth**', '**quake**'

User enter '**virtual reality**': returns **all 3** records

User enter '**reality virtual**': **Earth, quake**

I am using t-sql for search, full-text-search is enabled and used to also find a keywords in main text. C# is middle tier. But I prefer to have solution on t-sql level.

**UPDATE 1**
First what I am going to do, is to disallow spaces in tags, like on stackoverflow. Any other ideas are upreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to investigate using the [Velocity](http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity) caching engine, as it has quite rich support for tagging ([GetObjectsByTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.caching.datacache.getobjectsbytag.aspx), [GetObjectsByAllTags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.caching.datacache.getobjectsbyalltags.aspx), [GetObjectsByAnyTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.caching.datacache.getobjectsbyanytag.aspx)) and all the hard work has been done for you! All you have to do is load your objects into the cache with appropriate tags.

Comment: Thanks for link, I wasn't aware of it. I will definitely examine it.
However, this is only part of my search problem, and there is low chance that I can use 3rd party.

Comment: Depends how you interpret 3rd party. If you're already using C# then it's just another component from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You require a split function to split the tags in the search string, and then try to match these in the tags

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
        @String VARCHAR(8000) ,
        @Delimiter  VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS @RetTable TABLE(
        String varchar(1000)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT ,
            @j INT
    SELECT  @i = 1
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@String)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @j = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @i + 1)
        IF @j = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @j = LEN(@String) + 1
        END
        INSERT  @RetTable SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, @i, @j - @i)))
        SELECT  @i = @j + LEN(@Delimiter)
    END
    RETURN
END


DECLARE @String VARCHAR(8000) ,
        @Delimiter  VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @RetTable TABLE(
        String varchar(1000)
)

SELECT  @String = 'world of ',
        @Delimiter = ' '

--split FUNCTION that returns a table of tags to match
    DECLARE @i INT ,
            @j INT
    SELECT  @i = 1
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@String)
    BEGIN
        PRINT @i
        SELECT  @j = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @i + 1)
        IF @j = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @j = LEN(@String) + 1
        END
        INSERT  @RetTable SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, @i, @j - @i)))

        SELECT  @i = @j + LEN(@Delimiter)
    END

SELECT * FROM @RetTable
--split FUNCTION that returns a table of tags to match

DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Objects VARCHAR(MAX),
        Tags VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Objects,Tags) SELECT 'Earth', 'World,reality'
INSERT INTO @Table (Objects,Tags) SELECT 'World of warcraft 3', 'World Of warcraft,virtual,reality'
INSERT INTO @Table (Objects,Tags) SELECT 'quake', 'game,virtual'


SELECT  DISTINCT 
        t.* 
FROM    @Table t,
        @RetTable r
WHERE   Tags LIKE '%' + String + '%,%'
OR      Tags LIKE '%,%' + String + '%,%'
OR      Tags LIKE '%,%' + String + '%'
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT a good idea to put such complex business logic into your SQL code! Put it in the middle tier and if you're worried about performance use some caching mechanism.

Comment: good point. However, I afraid that it will be to slow to match all combinations of keywords  to tags in C# level.

Comment: The opposite is true. Unless you have a MASSIVE amount of keywords (>100MB) you will not require Full Text indexing. And you could always implement c# indexing with nested hashtables/dictionnaries.

Comment: Although, unless your database (which is unique) you can actually have multiple servers using the C# code... there is natural parallelism here!